# Ghci error: No instance for Show

Tags: haskell

This works in the ghci

```
data MyList a = Empty | Cons a (MyList a) deriving (Show, Eq, Read, Ord)

let x = Cons(21, Cons(12, Empty))
```

However when I type:

```
Prelude> x
```

I get this error:

```
No instance for (Show (MyList (Integer, MyList (Integer, MyList a0) ->
MyList (Integer, MyList a0)) ->
MyList (Integer, MyList (Integer, MyList a0) ->
MyList (Integer, MyList a0)))) arising from a use of `print'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for function application. The following code does what you want:

```
let x = Cons 21 (Cons 12 Empty)
```

The reason for this is that the `Cons` constructor is a curried function, but you are treating it as an uncurried function.

### Curried functions

Consider the following function adding two integers:

```
add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
add = \x -> (\y -> x + y)
```

Here we say `add` is a function, which takes an argument `x` of type `Int` and returns a function,
which takes an argument `y` of type `Int` and returns `x + y` of type `Int`.

We can apply this function for example as `(add 1) 2` evaluating to `3`.

Function application is *left-associative* in Haskell, which means that we don't need the parentheses
in `(add 1) 2` and can simply write `add 1 2`.

The function type constructor `->` is *right-associative* in Haskell, which means that we don't need the parentheses in `add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)` and can simply write `add :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

Also we don't have to explicitly define `add` using lambdas and can use the following notation:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y
```

Encoding multi-parameter functions as single-parameter functions returning single-parameter functions is quite common in Haskell. This approach has the nice property, that we can also partially apply a function. For example the following function takes a single `Int` and adds 2:

```
add2 :: Int -> Int
add2 x = add 2 x
```

But we can also *partially apply* `add` and simply write:

```
add2 :: Int -> Int
add2 = add 2
```

This is also called *point-free notation*, where parameters are referred to as points.

### Uncurried functions

An alternative encoding of multi-parameter functions can be done using tuple-values, i.e.

```
add' :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add' (x, y) = x + y
```

We can invoke this function for example as `add' (2, 3)`, which constructs the pair `(2, 3) :: (Int, Int)` and passes it as a single argument to the `add'` function.

### Uncurried <-> Curried

In the standard library are two functions to convert functions between the two styles.

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y = f (x, y)

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f (x, y) = f x y
```

For example `curry add'` gives us `add`, and `uncurry add` gives us `add'`.

### Back to explaining ghci's rambling

Note that we could also write the uncurried application as `add'(2, 3)`, which together with partial application and polymorphism explains why `let x = Cons(21, Cons(12, Empty))` doesn't directly lead to an error, but ghci subsequently says misterious things about the evaluation of `x`.
What happens here is that `(12, Empty)` is pair of type `(Int, MyList a)` for some type `a`.
This pair is then used as the first argument in `Cons (12, Empty)`, so we get a partially applied function which takes
a `MyList (Int, MyList a)` and appends `(12, Empty)` as an element to this list.
The same happens for `Cons(21, Cons(12, Empty))` where we partially apply a pair of 21 and the before mentioned partial function. In the end we tell ghci to print a function, which it cannot display and hence complains about a missing `Show` instance for the corresponding function type.